# Different user IDs [discord.js]

Tags: javascript

So I'm working in a discord bot where I want to add different user Ids in a command but now it doesn't work. the code looks like this:

```
if (message.author.id !== '513773028606476308', '749446086493470751') return message.channel.send("no")
```

Comment: The best way to do this programatically is using an array to store the ids and a loop to iterate over all of them

Comment: `(message.author.id !== '513773028606476308', '749446086493470751')` Does not do what you think it does, it does not check if `message.author.id` is equal to `513773028606476308` or `749446086493470751`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a command only to run **ONLY** for users with specific IDs. Therefore that `if` statement would be in some kind of function that handles that specific command.. your answer would be to change that if statement to

```
if (!['513773028606476308', '749446086493470751'].includes(message.author.id)){return message.channel.send("no")}
```

However, the best solution would be to have an array of these special IDs in the first place like

```
let allowed=['513773028606476308', '749446086493470751']
if (!allowed.includes(message.author.id)){return message.channel.send("no")}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that are contributing to the problem you're seeing here.

The first is that your `if` statement isn't set up properly. To do what you're looking for, it'd have to look like `if (message.author.id !== '513773028606476308' && message.author.id !== '749446086493470751')`. While being able to just comma-seperate those values would be a nice feature, it's not currently something you can do in Javascript. You have to explicitly say "if the author ID is not equal to `513773028606476308` and the author ID is not equal to `749446086493470751`" etc.

All that said, just continuously adding IDs on that `if` statement probably isn't a really good idea. Like commenters have pointed out, structuring this a bit differently would probably result in code that's both more readable and easier to change in the future. You'd do this by putting those user IDs in an array and then checking if the array doesn't contain those IDs, like so:

```js
let admins = ['749446086493470751', '749446086493470751'];
if (!admins.includes(message.author.id)) {
    return message.channel.send("no");
}
```

This makes your life a little easier down the line for a few reasons:

- If you want to have other commands that only these two users can use, you don't have to copy-paste that big long `if` block elsewhere, it's fairly simple and easy.
- If you do add another command like this, and then later want to add a third special user, you only have to change your code in one place (the admins array), rather than potentially missing a spot.